Laplacian Integral is bounded by product of constant K and real part to the power of $\alpha$: $|\int f^{\star}(x)e^{-wx}dx| \leq K |u|^{\alpha}$
I am trying to understand a proof of an old research paper by M. Crum from 1955. It is about approximating functions in $L_p$ space by exponential functions. In short words, there is an inequality in the proof, which I don't understand and no hints are given, how it was established, and I can't ask the author, because he is long dead. So maybe, some of you experts, can kindly look over my arguments?
First, the following function definition (I assume, it is a Laplace transformation) is given:
$$F(\omega) := \int_{0}^{\infty} f^{\star}(x) e^{-wx} dx \text{ with } w=u+iv, Re(u) > 0$$
Whereby, it is assumed that: $f^{\star} \in L_q, \text{and } g:= e^{-wx} \in X \subset L_p(0,\infty) \text{ with } 1 \leq p \leq \infty$
The author then deduces the following inequality:
$$| F(\omega)| \leq K \cdot |u|^{\alpha}, (\alpha \geq 0).$$
This conclusion is not obvious to me, but maybe there is some applicable theorem out there, which I don't know yet? Anyhow, my try in proving this inequality was to use the Hölder inequality for the $L_p(0,\infty)$ space, i.e., my arguments are as follows:
According to Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis Theorem 3.8, it follows that $f \cdot g \in L_1(\mu)$, with $\mu$ as a positive measure function. Additionally, the standard modulus estimate for integrals allows that
$$ |F(\omega)| = |\int_{0}^{\infty} f^{\star}(x) \cdot e^{-wx} dx| \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} | f^{\star}(x) \cdot e^{-wx}| dx. $$
Now the Hölder inequality comes into play:
$$ = \lVert f^{\star} \cdot e^{-wx} \rVert_1 \leq \lVert f^{\star}\rVert_q \cdot \lVert e^{-wx}\rVert_p = K_1 \cdot \lVert e^{-wx} \rVert_p,$$
with $K_1$ as a constant, because $f^{\star}$ is known to be bounded in $L_q$. Additionally, the modulus of the complex exponential function can be simplified, i.e., $|e^{u+iv}| = e^{u}$, thus
$$ = K_1 \cdot \lVert e^{-wx}\rVert_p = K_1 \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x\cdot u} = K_1 \cdot \big[-e^{-x u } \cdot \frac{1}{u}\big]_0^{\infty}$$
Because of $Re(w) > 0$, it follows:
$$ = K_1 \cdot |u|^{-1} .$$
However, I am unsure how this relates to the wished result of $\leq K \cdot |u|^{-\alpha}$ with $\alpha \geq 0$: according to my result, it must be the case that $\alpha = 1$.
So, my question is, did I use the wrong approach, or is there some step missing, did I misinterpret the statement in the original paper, or must the result in the paper be wrong? - any constructive comments in improving my posed question or finding some answer to it are warmly welcome.
cheers and best wishes to you all :-)

I saw an answer here yesterday, but now no more, where have you gone dear friend? :)
